# Docker add files to VOLUME

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a `Dockerfile` which copies some files into the container and after that creates a VOLUME.

```
...
ADD src/ /var/www/html/
VOLUME /var/www/html/files
...
```

In the `src` folder is an files folder and in this files folder are some files I need to have copied to the VOLUME the first time the container gets started.

I thought the first time the container gets created it uses the content of the original dir specified in the volume but this is not the case.

So how can I get the files into this folder?
Do I need to create an extra folder and copy it with a runscript (I hope not)?

Comment: It should work and to be 200% sure I've just tested it.  The only case it wouldn't work as you expect is if by using `-v /path/to/some/directory:/var/www/...` in docker-run or docker-compose.

Answer (score 23):

Whatever you put in your Dockerfile is just evaluated at **build time** (and not when you are *creating* a new container).

If you want to make file from the host available in your container use a [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume):

```
docker run -v /host_dir:/container_dir ...
```

In case you just want to copy files from the host to a container as a one-off operation you can use:

```
docker cp /host_dir mycontainer:/container_dir
```

Comment: I want to add the files on build time so I have initial files in the folder. But I want then make this folder available to my host via a data volume. So the initial files should be placed into the data volume. I can copy the files via a start script in the container, but I hope there is a more elegant solution. If not I will do it via the script

Answer (score 6):

The issue is with your ADD statement.   Also you might not understand how volumes are accessed.   Compare your efforts with the demo below:

```
FROM alpine #, or your favorite tiny image
ADD src/files /var/www/html/files
VOLUME /var/www/html/files
```

Build an image called 'dataimg':

```
docker build -t dataimg .
```

Use the dataimg image to create a data container named 'datacon':

```
docker run --name datacon dataimg /bin/cat
```

Mount the volume from datacon in your nginx container:

```
docker run --volumes-from datacon nginx ls -la /var/www/html/files
```

And you'll see the listing of /var/www/html/files reflects the contents of src/files